# Laravel Dingo nested transformers

Tags: laravel, dingo-api

I'm trying to get one to many relationship objects with transformers. I want to get include metas but i only get just regular transform fields.

my transformer:

```
class AssistantTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'assistantmetas'
    ];

    public function transform(User $user)
    {
        return [
            'id'        => (int) $user->id,
            'firstname' => ucfirst($user->first_name),
            'lastname'  => ucfirst($user->last_name),
        ];
    }


    public function includeMetas(User $user)
    {
        $assistantmetas = $user->userMetas;

        return $this->item($assistantmetas, new AssistantsMetaTransformer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `defaultIncludes` not available includes, because it needs to send request via `url? include=assistantmetas` to get result like this.